# Google Spreadsheet Query; Keep Background Color

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with a whole bunch of data, where parts of it are queried to present in more readable ways. The problem is that the initial data also has background colors set, which are not taken over by the query result. Is there an easy way to do this? 
[image: Example of what I mean]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible, because formulas do not transfer background colors. the only way is to use script, or set up some conditional formatting rule.

Comment: I was hoping to not rely on conditional formatting as it decouples the coloring effectively. But I guess that's how it's going to be then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be to use conditional formatting to re-create the background color. custom formula would be:

```
=D1="test1"
```

applied to range **D1:D**